# How does one prove associativity, commutativity, etc of an empty set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler one of the exercises is as follows:

`"The empty set is not a vector space. The empty set fails to satisfy only one of the requirements listed in 1.19. Which one?"`

1.19 lists the requirements of a vector space. I.e. associativity, commutativity, additive identity, additive inverse, multiplicative inverse, and distributive property.

The answer to the question is that the empty set doesn't satisfy additive identity due to the fact that there is no element $\mathbf{0}$ in vector space $\mathbf{V}$.

How does one going about proving that the empty set meets the other requirements of associativity, commutativity, additive inverse, multiplicative inverse, and the distributive property?

I'm confused about how the elements of an empty set can be shown to follow these properties when they don't exist.

Comment: Those properties are satisfied [vacuously](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: In order to note be commutative, there must exist elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1+x_2\neq x_2+x_1$. Do such elements exist?

Comment: They do not. So due to that antecedent not being satisfied the properties in 1.19 are satisfied. Vacuous truth is new to me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the other answers, one way I like to look at this this situation is as follows:

All the of the axioms you list: associativity, commutativity, additive inverse, etc... all start with the quantifier "for all". In other words, if you wrote them out with heavy notation they would have the form $\forall x P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is some further property of $x$. To say that a space *fails* to satisfy such a statement amounts to saying that the space satisfies the *negation* of the statement, which has the form $\exists x Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ is the negation of $P(x)$. So right away we see that an empty space cannot satisfy such a statement since it's asserting that there is some element of the space.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can understand it by example. Example 1:
prove that my favorite set $\{1,4,9,12\}$ meets the requirements of associativity.
Approach: Pick elements and start testing:

test #1:    $ (1 + 4) + 9 = 1 + (4 + 9)$. Obviously true.

test #2:    $ (12 + 4) + 9 = 12 + (4 + 9)$. Obviously true.
to finish the proof, you'd have to walk through all combinations -- a finite number $k$ of tests to pass in this example.

Example 2:
prove that your favorite set $\{\,\}$ meets the requirements of associativity.
Again pick elements and start testing... but we cannot form even one test without any elements. So we have no tests to conduct ($k=0$). Loosely speaking, "Since we did not fail, we have succeeded." More properly "A implies B" is true, with A being: $a,b,c$ are any elements of $\{\,\}$ , and B representing the associativity equation. "A implies B" is equivalent to "(not A) or B", and A never holds.

Comment: It does not fail any of the requirements, but it doesn't satisfy them either.

Comment: I guess the concept of succeeding without tests is confusing to me. I'll keep this example in mind, along with vacuous truth, as I continue learning. Thanks!

Comment: @K.defaoite That's good point. It doesn't satisfy the requirements. But since the antecedent (which requires elements to be true) is false, does that mean the requirements are met vacuously?

Comment: I made a second draft which i think addresses your question.  "which requires elements to be true" is a good way to think about it. and yes vacuously is word usually used.

Comment: @K.defaoite that sounds too excessive to me. For instance, in that case the empty set is not a topological space, as it would not *satisfy* any of the requirements (by the same reasoning). A "for all" statement is always vacuously satisfied over the empty set, but the word 'vacuous' there does not negate the fact that it does indeed satisfy them. The problem with the empty set not being a vector space is of that it does not have a neutral element; but that is not a "for all" statement, but rather an *existential* statement. (See also halrankard's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

or maybe you'd prefer to look at it this way:

Example 3:  Prove that the system of 2 by 2 matrices does not enjoy the commutative property. We are done if there exists one pair of elements where commutativity fails. We can give this explicitly:

$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{array}  
\right]\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array}  
\right] \neq \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array}  
\right]\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{array}  
\right],\,\,\,\text{q.e.d.} 
$$

Example 4:  Prove that the system $\{\,\}$ does not enjoy the commutative property. We are done if there exists one pair of elements where commutativity fails. But we cannot find a pair of elements, period. It seems the claim is false.

Example 5:  Prove that the system $\{\,\}$ does enjoy the commutative property. We must show "A implies B", with A = (L and M are elements of $\{\,\}$) and B = (LM = ML). Here A can never be true, so the implication arrow is never "activated". More formally, "A implies B" = "(not A) or B" holds, because "not A" holds always.